# Javascript give array Key a name while doing an array 'push'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 groups of radio buttons each containing multiple ones. While using the `data-toggle="buttons"` in bootstrap3 for each group I can make sure, only one answer is selected per group. So far everything is fine.

The function below is triggered on a click event and returns the values of the selected items. My problem is how can I handle the returning values stored in the array `values` and give each key a name corresponding to the group set of buttons.

Assuming I select `Red + small + Circle` then `getValues` will return the key=> values :

- [0] => Red
- [1] => Small
- [2] => Circle

Now, if I select `small + Circle` :

- [0] => Small
- [1]=> Circle

The values are stored as per the order of selection, Im trying to get this values to build a query as per the selection..

Where I want the values to be store in this format :

- [color] =>x
- [size] => y
- [shape] => z

d

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"/> Red     /// Grp 1 Color
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"/> Blue
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="small"/> small   /// Grp2  Size
<input type="radio" name="size" value ="Large"/> Large
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="shape" value="circle"/> Circle  /// Grp3 Shape
<input type="radio" name="shape" value="square"/> Square


function getValues(){

var values = [];
for(var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++){
    if(radios[x].type == "radio" && radios[x].checked){
       values.push(radios[x].value);
    }
}
return values;

}

$( "#Btn" ).click(function() {
      var x = getValues();

$.each(x, function(k, v) {

//display the key and value pair
      alert(k + ' is ' + v);

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Arrays do not have index names you want an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677033/creating-object-key-with-jquery-each-loop This might help you

Comment: there is no associative array in javascript

Comment: You can perhaps specify the value attributes as `color:red`, `size:small` etc. instead of just `red`, `small` etc. And then split and have your own keys easily by processing what you get.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware the absence of associate arrays in javascript...
@Chavan - Thanks for the useful link

Comment: @user3003977 associate arrays is possible in js and check my answer and live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q7qw5/1/)

I think Associate array is possible in Javascript.

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html

```
<input type="radio" name="color" class="radioGrp" value="red"/> Red  
<input type="radio" name="color" class="radioGrp" value="blue"/> Blue
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="size" class="radioGrp" value="small"/> small
<input type="radio" name="size" class="radioGrp" value ="Large"/> Large
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="shape" class="radioGrp" value="circle"/>circle
<input type="radio" name="shape" class="radioGrp" value="square"/>square

<input type='button' id="Btn" />


function getValues(){

var values = [];
var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("radioGrp");
    console.log(radios);

for(var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++){
    if(radios[x].type == "radio" && radios[x].checked){
       values[radios[x].name] = (radios[x].value);
    }
}
  return values;
}

$("#Btn").click(function() {
      var x = getValues();

     alert(x["color"]);
     alert(x["size"]);
     alert(x["shape"]);

     for(var prop in x ){
       alert( prop + " is " + x[prop] );
     }

});
```

You can't use $.each for asscioate array for more details http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4319

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, Arrays are treated differently in JS. What you really want is a Hash Table... which is JS is just an object (sort of).

A technique you can use is to create an Array-Like object that has both the names as keys and indexes.

It's important to note that this isn't a full featured array-like object because it doesn't implement push, pop, slice, etc...

```
var values = {},
    length = 0;

for(var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++){
    if(radios[x].type == "radio" && radios[x].checked){
        //Assign the name as a key on the object
        values[radios[x].name] = radios[x].value;

        //Also assign the index as a key
        values[x] = radios[x].value;

        length += 1;
    }
}

values.length = length;

return values;
```

So what does this do for you exactly?

Well, it allows you to access the individual items by key:

```
values['bob'];
```

And it also allows you to access them by index:

```
values[0];
```

Even better, you can iterate over them using a normal for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
   //I act just like an array!!
   values[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Josh. Jus the part assign the index as a key shouldn't be values[x] = radios[x].name; instead ?

Comment: @user3003977 - I guess it just depends on if you want the names in there or the values.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below:

```
    function getValues(){

    var values = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++){
        if(radios[x].type == "radio" && radios[x].checked){
            var tmp={};
            tmp[radios[x].name]=radios[x].value;  
           values.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    return values;

    }

    $( "#Btn" ).click(function() {
          var x = getValues();

    $.each(x, function(k, v) {

    //display the key and value pair
          alert(k + ' is ' + v);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample code below get all selected checkbox as array

```
// A function that return an array with the selected items
function getSelected() {

  var selected = [];

  var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

  for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
     if(checkboxes[i].checked){
        selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
     }
  }

  return selected;

}
```

Note that this work with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could look something in line of this:

```
<script>
function getValues() {
  var values={};
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(inputs);
  for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;++i) 
     if (inputs[i].type==="radio" && inputs[i].checked) 
        values[inputs[i].name]=inputs[i].value;
 console.log(values);
}
</script>
<button onclick="getValues()">Hit me</button>
```

I know this is not jQuery - but you should be able to convert it :)

This will create an object from which you can pick the key-values pairs in proper order:

```
[ values.color||"default", values.size||"default", values.shape||"default" ]
```