# Giving a name to the object within array.push()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

In a part of my code, I am extracting data from a JSON file and place it in an object based array.

I receive the data successfully and can put each on on single object within an array. the only issue is, I want to give a name to each object.

```js
var playlist_data = {
  "Music1": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 1",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 1"
  },
  "Music2": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 2",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 2"
  },
  "Music3": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 3",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 3"
  },
  "Music4": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 4",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 4"
  }
};
var links = [];
$.each(playlist_data, function(index, element) {
  links.push({
    spotify: element.spotify,
    soundcloud: element.soundcloud,
  });
});

console.log(links);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the above code seems like replicating the same JSON data but it is a simplified version.

So in result I would like to call it like `links.Music2` and `links.Music2.spotify`

Comment: You cannot name elements in an array, so you need to use an object. *However* then you are back to the *exact* same data structure your JSON has, so your loop is completely redundant

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes thats right. But the main json file is way longer than this with various data. So I like to make a smaller version of main json with specific data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties) See also [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/215552)

Comment: and [Javascript give array Key a name while doing an array 'push'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21406185/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Since Javascript does not support named indexes, you would have to make `links` an object in order to access its properties via `links.Music2.spotify`. This is easily done however, it would just give you the exact same data you began with:

```js
var playlist_data = {
  "Music1": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 1",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 1"
  },
  "Music2": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 2",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 2"
  },
  "Music3": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 3",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 3"
  },
  "Music4": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 4",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 4"
  }
};
var links = {};
$.each(playlist_data, function(index, element) {
  links[index]= {
    spotify: element.spotify,
    soundcloud: element.soundcloud,
  };
});

console.log(links);
console.log(links.Music2.spotify)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can name your each obj with code like below

```
var playlist_data = {
  "Music1": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 1",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 1"
  },
  "Music2": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 2",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 2"
  },
  "Music3": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 3",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 3"
  },
  "Music4": {
    "soundcloud": "Soundcloud Music 4",
    "spotify": "Spotify Music 4"
  }
};
var links = [];
$.each(playlist_data, function(index, element) {
  links.push({
    spotify: element.spotify,
    soundcloud: element.soundcloud,
  });
});

let myMusic = {};

for(let x = 0 ; x < links.length ; x++)
{
    let z = Number(x+1);
    myMusic["music"+z] = links[x];
}

console.log(myMusic.music1);
```

Answer (score -1):

As it seems you want to use the `spotify` as a key for the `links`.

There are two types of array in JS:

standard array which is : `[ ]`

associative array which is : `{ }`!

As you see you can use `{ }` which also stands as an object in javascript as an array. And then you can use `spotify` as the key.
So your code will be like below:

```
var links = {};
$.each(playlist_data, function(index, element) {
  links[index] = {
    spotify: element.spotify,
    soundcloud: element.soundcloud,
  };
});
console.log(links_s.Music1.spotify) // Spotify Music 1
```